# iOS Camera Overlay Capture Image

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, avfoundation

I am facing some real though issues. I have studied couple of tutorial for adding overlay in camera using UIImagePickerController and AVFoundation. Everything is working fine for me. I can add overlay on camera using both. However my main concern is to extract that part of image which is under that overlay view when user hits scan button. I am having a white view in overlay and a button, so image under that white view should only be retrieved.

```
-(IBAction)cameraClicked:(id)sender {

    OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController 
    isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) {
        self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode =     
        UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    }
    else {
        self.imagePickerController.sourceType =    
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }

    self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.imagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;      
    self.imagePickerController.toolbarHidden = YES;

    self.imagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform =     
    CGAffineTransformScale(self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, 
    CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X,CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);
    self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES     
    completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    CGRect cropRect;
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *crosshair = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height));
    [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(isIOS7)
        cropRect = CGRectMake(10, 440, crosshair.size.width, crosshair.size.height);
    else
        cropRect = CGRectMake(10, 405, crosshair.size.width, crosshair.size.height);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage *setImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    self.finalImageView.image = setImage;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this... its Working..

```
  self.imagePickerController=nil;
  self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
  self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
  self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

// create view for overlay

```
 CGRect overlayRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imagePickerController.view.frame.size.width,      self.imagePickerController.view.frame.size.height);

    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:overlayRect];

    btn_Overlay = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn_Overlay setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMageNmae"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn_Overlay.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 170, 150.0, 30.0);
    btn_Overlay.tag = 0;
    [btn_Overlay setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_Overlay addTarget:self action:@selector(ActinMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [overlayView addSubview:btn_Overlay];

[self.imagePickerController setCameraOverlayView:overlayView];
    // display imagePicker
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have done this, however when i click on button action method, i need to extract that image which is showing in camera inside overlay view.

Comment: you can extract iamge (ActinMethod). write code in Action Method     [self.imagePickerController takePicture];